# PC COBOL program to JCL

Tags: cobol, jcl, gnucobol

I have the following simple COBOL program - written for the PC.  It simply reads a file from the computer and writes to the file:

```
ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
FILE-CONTROL.
SELECT CUSTOMER-FILE ASSIGN TO
"C:Customers.dat"
ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
DATA DIVISION.
FILE SECTION.
FD CUSTOMER-FILE.
01 CUSTOMER-RECORD.
05 FIRST-NAME PIC X(20).
05 LAST-NAME PIC X(20).
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
01 WS-CUSTOMER-RECORD.
05 WS-FIRST-NAME PIC X(20).
05 WS-LAST-NAME PIC X(20).
01 WS-EOF PIC X.
PROCEDURE DIVISION.
OPEN OUTPUT CUSTOMER-FILE
PERFORM UNTIL CUSTOMER-RECORD = SPACES
DISPLAY "Enter the first and last name for the customer"
ACCEPT CUSTOMER-RECORD
WRITE CUSTOMER-RECORD
END-PERFORM
CLOSE CUSTOMER-FILE
DISPLAY "Output from the Customer File:"
OPEN INPUT CUSTOMER-FILE.
PERFORM UNTIL WS-EOF = 'Y'
READ CUSTOMER-FILE INTO WS-CUSTOMER-RECORD
AT END MOVE 'Y' TO WS-EOF
NOT AT END DISPLAY WS-CUSTOMER-RECORD
END-READ
END-PERFORM.
CLOSE CUSTOMER-FILE.
GOBACK.
```

My question:  I'm not too familiar with JCL.  So if I were to put this program on a mainframe, what would I do for the JCL?

Comment: *reads a file from the computer and writes to the file* This presumes you have [files](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos-basic-skills?topic=zc-zos-storage-constructs-file-systems-data-sets-more). You certainly won't have `C:`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume your Identification Division got lost in a cut & paste incident on its way to Stack Overflow; you'll need that.

The current incarnation of IBM Enterprise COBOL does not allow free format source so in order to get your code to compile you would have to reformat and follow the traditional fixed format.

Rather than referring to your data file by name, your [Assign clause](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/6.3?topic=section-assign-clause) must refer to a name (limited to 8 characters) which corresponds to a DD name in your JCL.  Pick something meaningful, to the extent you can in 8 characters, maybe CUSTOMER.

Since you're running with JCL, your [Accept statement](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/6.3?topic=statements-accept-statement) will work a bit differently.  Probably data will come from a SYSIN DD.

Your JCL will look something like this...

```
[job card, which is shop-specific]
//TOMSPGM  EXEC PGM=yourProgramName
//STEPLIB  DD  DISP=SHR,DSN=mainframe.dataset.where.you.bound.your.program
//SYSIN    DD  *
[your customer records]
//CUSTOMER DD  DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE),
//             DSN=mainframe.dataset.where.your.data.should.end.up,
//             LRECL=40,
//             AVGREC=U,
//             RECFM=FB,
//             SPACE=(40,(10,10),RLSE) Adjust to your needs
//SYSOUT       SYSOUT=*
//CEEDUMP      SYSOUT=*
```

I'm not sure how this will work with your creating the customer file and then reading it in the same program.  In 30 years of mainframe work I've never seen that.

Comment: I don't see a reason why reading a data set created and written in the same step would not work with COBOL. As soon as the data set has been closed after writing, the system has the information required to open for input.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to answer from @cschneid.

Great to see `AVGREC` is being used on the DD statement to allocate space for the data set. This is much better than using the old-fashioned `CYL`, or `TRK` units.
Unfortunately, IMHO, the IBM z/OS architects missed to implement a more modern was to specify space: KiB, or MiB. (ISPF supports KB, and MB as space unit, JCL doesn't.)

With `AVGREC` you tell the system that the `SPACE=` primary and secondary space values are *number of records*, instead of physical units such as tracks, or cylinders.

```
//CUSTOMER DD  ...
//             AVGREC=U,
//             SPACE=(40,(10,20),RLSE)
```

Above statement tells the system that the records written will have an average length of 40 bytes (this completely is independent of `RECFM=`, or `LRECL=`!). With `AVGREC=U` (`U` means *units*), this further tells the system to allocate initial (primary) space for 10 records, and to add additional space for 20 records each time more space is needed (with an upper limit).

Physical allocations are still in tracks, or cylinders under the hood. The system calculates tracks, or cylinders needed from

```
"average record length" * "number of records" * avgrec-unit
```

For the *primary* allocation, this is

```
40 * 10 * 1 = 400 bytes
```

Good. But how can we specify our space needs in KiB or MiB using these keywords?

Remember that the *average record length* in the `SPACE=` parameter is completely unreleated to the *actual record length* specified via `LRECL=`. Great, so we can freely choose the *average record length*, and set it to, say, 1. And let us also change the wording "number of records* in above forumla to "number of units". The formula becomes:

```
1 * "number of units" * avgrec-unit
```

or

```
"number of units" * avgrec-unit
```

`AVGREC=` supports the units `U` (1), `K` (1024), and `M` (1024*1024). So, to allocate space in megabytes (MiB), we simply code:

```
//CUSTOMER DD  ...
//             AVGREC=M,
//             SPACE=(1,(10,20),RLSE)
```

This will allocate 10 MiB primary space, and 20 MiB secondary space. Each allocation is rounded up to the next integral number of tracks, or cylinders, depending on physical disk structures. You simply don't have to care anymore. Neat, isn't it?